# Calculating term frequencies in a big corpus efficiently regardless of document boundaries

Tags: r, nlp, tm

I have a corpus of almost 2m documents. I want to calculate the term frequencies of the terms in the whole corpus, regardless of document boundaries.

A naive approach would be combining all the documents into one very big document and vectorising it.

An elaborate approach is building a full-blow TDM with `tm` or any tool, where one would have the term frequencies of each term in each document, and thus in the whole corpus. Here is how I do it:

```
# Build a TDM from the 'corpus' tibble using a filtered 'texts' column:

htgs = VCorpus(VectorSource(subset(x = corpus,
                                   subset = condition)$texts))
# Some preprocessing
htgs = preprocess(htgs)

# Consider terms whose length is between 2 and Inf in the TDM (the default is 3 to Inf):
dtm_htgs = TermDocumentMatrix(htgs,
                              control = list(wordLengths=c(2, Inf)))
```

```
> dtm_htgs
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 495679, documents: 1983567)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 5361931/983207145062
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 170
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

However, trying to unpack the sparse matrix that results from this attempt is, expectedly, uttering out the memory error:

```
> m = as.matrix(dtm_htgs)

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7325.5 Gb
```

How to disregard per-document counts and suffice with the global term frequencies in the corpus as a whole, which can save up a lot of memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change the data structure of `VectorSource`'s input from `character vector` to `tibble`, I apparently get what I want as the function automatically integrates all texts into one document:

```
> class(subset(corpus, condition)$texts)
[1] "character"
```

```
> class(subset(corpus, condition, select = texts))
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

```
htgs = VCorpus(VectorSource(subset(x = corpus,
                                   subset = condition,
                                   select = texts)))

# Same code as in the question: 
htgs = preprocess(htgs)
dtm_htgs = TermDocumentMatrix(htgs,
                              control = list(wordLengths=c(2, Inf)))
```

```
> dtm_htgs
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 495679, documents: 1)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 495679/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 170
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

And finally the frequency counts can be simply obtained using:

```
m = as.matrix(dtm_htgs)

# Corpus counts
v = sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d = data.frame(word = names(v),freq=unname(v))
```

This practically removes the sparsity and saves a lot of RAM, which is extremely efficient and enables me to continue working on the data.

Upon analysing a sample of 10 documents, I found the produced term frequencies to be valid. There may be a simpler way to achieve that, but his is very efficient and does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
library("quanteda")

topfeats <- tokens(corpus$text, remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
  dfm() %>%
  topfeatures()
```

Depending on your RAM and the size of your documents, it should work with 2 million documents.  The results is a named vector of global term frequencies where the name is the term, and the value is the frequency.